# Count Number of invoices in oracle APPS

Tags: invoices, oracle-apps

i want a query to display how many invoices are created using a particular interface for the last one month in AR module. we are not using any other module except ar,ap ,gl.All our invoices are generated through interface only.Please tell me the table which i can find all the invoices created in AR module using a particular Interface.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds simple to me but I don't have a lot of AR experience.
`select count(*) 
from 
AP_INVOICES_ALL
where
CREATION_DATE > SYSDATE - 30
and SOURCE = '&source'
;`